# Javascript and JQuery UI on Rails: won't display without page refresh

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I'm new to both Ruby on Rails and Javascript so wasn't sure how to proceed. I have an app that uses some of the snazzy JQuery UI components, specifically Datepicker and Tabs. They both work, but only once I've refreshed the page at least once; on first load I just get html as if the jquery javascript files weren't there in app/assets/javascripts, which they are.

Any ideas? Failing making it load first time, how can I automatically refresh the page?

application.js:

```
$(function() {
  $("#event_start_time").datepicker();
  $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

view.html.erb:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#students"><span>Students</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#teachers"><span>Teachers</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="students">
    <%= render 'sessions/student_login_details' %>
  </div>
  <div id="organisations">
    <%= render 'sessions/teacher_login_details' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

application.html.erb:

```
  <head>
    <%= yield :scripts %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
  </body>
```

EDIT: Okay, solved it. It was Turbolinks in the billiards room with the lead piping. This gem https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks helpfully explains why it occasionally makes Javascripts not function normally. Thanks all!

Comment: Have you had a look to the Browser development tools? What does it say about the JQuery file? Is it loaded? Any console outputs?

Comment: Loaded, yes, but not appearing properly. It's okay, I believe it's Turbolinks causing javascripts not to display properly.

Answer (score 0):

You're using turbolinks without including the turbolinks js file in your application.js

```
//= require turbolinks
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code a bit too much in the question - //=require turbolinks was already there.